# Creating class operator

Tags: c++, access-specifier, typecast-operator

Trying to create class operator:

```
class ggg
    {
    int a;
    int b;
    operator std::string ( ) 
        {
        return "hello";
        }

    };

int main() {

    ggg g ;
    std::string s =  g;
    cout<<s;

}
```

and got error:

```
'ggg::operator std::string' : cannot access private member declared in class 'ggg'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All members in classes are private by default.

```
class ggg
{
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    operator std::string ( ) 
    {
        return "hello";
    }

};
```

should solve your problems